# Second order differential equation $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-4\frac{dy}{dx}+4y= 2 e^{2x} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is 
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-4\frac{dy}{dx}+4y= 2 e^{2x}
$$

I have got the complementary function as $(A+Bx)e^{2x}=0$ but when finding the Particular integral when I substitute back I am getting zero? I have tried both $y=Ce^{2x}$ and $Cxe^{2x}$ ?

Comment: Your characteristic polynomial has a *double* root of $2$, so that you will need a *quadratic* polynomial times $e^{2x}$ to find a particular solution. One way to conclude this without having to come up with it yourself would be to guess $y=z(x)e^{2x}$ and solve a simpler ODE.

Comment: ohh i see. Thank you. So this only applies to double roots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homogenous solution:
$$
r^2-4r+4=0\Rightarrow y_h(x)=c_1e^{2x}+xc_2e^{2x}
$$
For the particular solution, guess it has the form $x^2e^{2x}$, since it must be linearly independent from the homogenous solution (see Wronskian). So by undetermined coefficients. Guess
$$
y(x)=Ax^2e^{2x}\\
y'(x)=2Axe^{2x}+2Ax^2e^{2x}\\
y''(x)=2Ae^{2x}+4Axe^{2x}+4Ax^2e^{2x}+4Axe^{2x}
$$
And use your original diffeq to solve for the coefficients.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Pumpkinpeach no problem. You can accept the answer if you felt it answered your question. This gives us both points.

Comment: Wait, can I ask why do guess x^2e^2x? Normally you'd have a coefficient there like Cxe^2x?

Comment: I said you guess a function of this form. As you can see in the answer I do put a coefficient

Comment: Oh yes ofcourse. Sorry. So I substituted back to get 2C(x-1)^2=2e^2x

Comment: What do I do next as there are 2 variables?

Comment: I don't understand. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I used the letter C instead of A. Same thing but I substituted back in ODE to find coefficients but don't know how to solve for the variable A/C and x?

Comment: why are you trying to solve for $x$? you are trying to determine the coefficients

Comment: this is a function for any x

Comment: Ohhh so you just ignore the x...?

Comment: @Pumpkinpeach in computing the values of the undetermined coefficients yes. I recommend you read up on the method of undetermined coefficients and understand the examples before proceeding

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much.